# Save figure by using MATLAB Command Window

Tags: matlab, shell, command-line, figure

I want to generate a figure and save it by using the MATLAB Command Window, after open it by a shell command from VBA.
The following error message is displayed when I try to open a figure:

[image]

In my MATLAB code I am using the following lines, to save the figure:

```
figure('Visible','off');
imagepath = 'myPath.jpg';
plot(1:100);
saveas(gcf,imagepath);
close(gcf);
```

Has anyone an idea or some experience with that kind of problem?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're saving something that's not your figure...
`gcf=figure('Visible','off');`
should do the trick...

Comment: gcf characterizes the active figure. The code works in the MATLAB environment, I guess the problem is something about generate a figure in the MATLAB Command Window